# Finding the indexes between differences in vectors

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have two lists. Let them be

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20]
B = [1, 2, 11, 12, 4, 5, 6, 13, 10, 21]
```

The rationale is that after some preprocessing some items in `A` can be expanded or shrunk onto some others in B.

In the above example, the first and second elements of both lists agree, while `A[2] = 3` is expanded to `B[2:4] = [11, 12]`. In contrast, `A[6:9] = [7, 8, 9]` is shrunk to `B[8] = 13`.

Finally, the length may be preserved and only the item changes. namely `A[10] = 20` becomes `B[10] = 21`.

I need to determine where the lists do not match, and I would like an output such as the one below (type of structure does not matter, I only want the indices to be known in one way or another)

```py
x = [{'original': [2], 'new': [2,4]}, 
    {'original': [6,9], 'new': [8]},
    {'original': [10], 'new': [10]}
    ]
```

EDIT: the example might be misleading, but `B` would normally be longer than `A`, and both strings could be of any arbitrary length.

Comment: This problem is generally known as producing a 'diff'. There a couple well-known diff algorithms, probably most famously the Myer's algorithm.

Comment: I suggest looking into [Levensthein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) ([python lib](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/)), "diff" libraries ([libxdiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html), [libxdiff](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libxdiff), [xdelta](http://xdelta.org/), [xdelta](https://github.com/jmacd/xdelta)), and [DNA alignment software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequence_alignment_software).

Comment: What will be the length of the lists? For relatively smaller values there are some pretty simple approaches

Comment: @AbhinavMathur 1k-2k items per list